# Big downloads thrash all my other connections

Tags: wireless-networking, internet

As the title says, big downloads on my 2017 Macbook Pro (latest OS) pretty much slow my other network connections to a crawl. Is there a way to configure my computer to more fairly allocate network resources to different processes?

Answer (score 0):

When fully utilizing your network bandwidth causes a spike in latency (lagginess), it’s almost always a problem with your network, known as bufferbloat.

Run http://dslreports.com/speedtest to see your bufferbloat score on your home network. Then consider using a solution such as an EvenRoute IQrouter to kill your network’s bufferbloat problem.

Comment: Tried that test... buffer bloat gives 'no result' just a grey icon with a dash - in it. Not sure what to make of that. DL210mbps, UL12mbps, which is about what we pay for.

Comment: I got an F for buffer bloat. I'll try fixing it. Thanks